# Почему коннектится только один из детей?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Произвести обмен данными между процессом-родителем и его дочерними процессами при помощи механизма каналов. Дочерние процессы по окончании посылают флаг окончания работы. Процесс-родитель постоянно обрабатывает сообщения из канала и выдаёт сообщение об окончании работы такого-то процесса.

```
STARTUPINFO fstartInfo;
STARTUPINFO sstartInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION fInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION sInfo;

LPTSTR f = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\PROCESS.EXE 12"));
LPTSTR s = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\PROCESS.EXE 16"));

ZeroMemory(&fstartInfo, sizeof(fstartInfo));
ZeroMemory(&sstartInfo, sizeof(sstartInfo));

fstartInfo.cb = sizeof(fstartInfo);
sstartInfo.cb = sizeof(sstartInfo);

char szPipe[64];
HANDLE hPipe;
int Buffer_in;
int count;
sprintf(szPipe, "\\\\.\\pipe\\name");
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(szPipe,PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 10, 0, sizeof(Buffer_in), 10, NULL );

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hPipe)
{
    printf("Server Pipe not created\n");
    exit(0);
}
else  
    printf("Successful in creating server pipe\n");

char *inBuffer;
int bResult;
int i=2;

if (!CreateProcess(NULL, f, NULL, NULL, FALSE, HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &fstartInfo, &fInfo))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "CreateProcess failed on error %d\n", GetLastError());
    ExitProcess(1);
}

if (!CreateProcess(NULL, s, NULL, NULL, FALSE, HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &sstartInfo, &sInfo))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "CreateProcess failed on error %d\n", GetLastError());
    ExitProcess(1);
}

while (!ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL)); 
printf("Client has connected\n");

while(i > 1)
{
    bResult=ReadFile(hPipe, (LPVOID) &Buffer_in, (DWORD) sizeof(Buffer_in), (LPDWORD) &count, (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);
    if(bResult) {
        i--;
        printf("revieved %d\n", Buffer_in);
    }
    else 
        printf("nothing");
}
CloseHandle(hPipe);
ExitProcess(1);
return 0;
```

Код родителя. Коннектится только один из детей. Что делаю не так? Спасибо.

Comment: А как должно быть? Открываете трубу, читаете, закрываете трубу, выходите. Всё нормально. Если хотите чего-то другого, то объясните -- чего.

Comment: хочу по этому каналу конектить с родителем два дочерних процесса

Comment: К одному instance канала одновременно может подключиться только один клиент. Поэтому Вам можно пойти двумя путями:
1. создать два instance одного именованного канала
2. слушать клиентов по очереди, т.е. после того как пообщались с первым клиентом не завершать серверный процесс а ждать коннект от второго клиента.